# Using $1 to extract some text with awk in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Hi i'm trying to write a script in order to extract a line if an expression is satisfied from a text file using awk.

So if i'm using this command in the shell i've right output but on the script it doesn't works maybe because $1 is recognized like the argument given by the user on shell.

that's my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a email=(test@test.com)
spam=`su - zimbra -c 'cat /var/log/zimbra.log | sed -n 's/.*sasl_username=//p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r' | awk '{if ($1>500){print $2}}'`
for i in "${email[@]}"
do
    echo "$spam"| /opt/zimbra/postfix/sbin/sendmail $i
done
```

but the email sent by the script has only this body :

```
su - zimbra -c 'cat /var/log/zimbra.log | sed -n 's/.*sasl_username=//p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r' | awk '{if (>500){print }}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Please provide a verifiable sample input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1
declare -a email=(test@test.com)
spam=`su - zimbra -c 'cat /var/log/zimbra.log | sed -n 's/.*sasl_username=//p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r' | awk -v var="$a" '{if (a>500){print $2}}'`
for i in "${email[@]}"
do
    echo "$spam"| /opt/zimbra/postfix/sbin/sendmail $i
done
```

Comment: thanks a lot that's works!

Comment: So from what I see it was a matter of using `-v var="$a"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the `$` char inside awk with `\`

```
spam=`su - zimbra -c 'cat /var/log/zimbra.log | sed -n 's/.*sasl_username=//p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r' | awk '{if (\$1>500){print \$2}}'`
```